# How can I learn some advanced logrotate techniques?

Tags: linux, logs, administration, logrotate

The `logrotate` section in the Linux administrator's handbook is very brief. The `man` page is ok but lacks examples. Where can I find some more comprehensive information, examples, and best-practice information for this command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [learning about general logging/logrotation on linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66292/learning-about-general-logging-logrotation-on-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [HowTo: The Ultimate Logrotate Command Tutorial with 10 Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/) from The Geek Stuff.

Comment: Please [provide context, not just links](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) in your answers...